# Where do I put in a get Request for a standard html page inside of my site?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

My code is this but I'm not sure If I need to put it in a JavaScript file or wrap script tags around it or put it in the head somewhere? Can you help me??

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-t3/games/2014/REG/schedule.xml?api_key=6wtn9jrvq9jmp7c4pv5g89kj";
request.open( "GET" , url );
request.send()
```

Comment: It's javascript. if you want it to be executed, you'll need `<script>` tags...

Comment: Thanks! What would be the proper retrieval request for this script so that it displays data on my webpage??

Comment: it's not going to work, because you're doing an ajax request to a completely different domain (unless you ARE api.sportsdatallc.com). you're going to run into the same-origin security restriction.

Comment: yeah I am api.sportsdatallc for the particular example. they've given me that api key. They let up the security restriction. I'm just not sure which retrieval request to use based on the code above??